# Taking on value of a tuple in an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

so I am creating a non-visible grid for a text based game. I have created an array of coordinates in a 10 by 10 grid. How do I access a single x and y value in the array?

----------Swift 3 Code!!

```
var gameArea: [(Int, Int)] = []

for x in 1...10 {
    for y in 1...10 {
        gameArea.append(x, y)
    }
}

var position = gameArea[5]

position.y
```

---

Comment: you forgot to name the elements of your tuple.


    `var gameArea: [(x: Int, y: Int)] = [ ]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access it like `.x` and `.y` you have to change a little bit your code also you can access it wit `.0` and `.1`

```
var gameArea: [(x: Int, y: Int)] = []

for x in 1...10 {
    for y in 1...10 {
        gameArea.append((x,y))
    }
}

var position = gameArea[5]

position.0 // x value
position.1 // y value

position.x // x value
position.y // y value
```

Answer (score 0):

Your append call needs to a single arguement which is a tuple, not two arguments which are elements of the tuple, like so:

```
gameArea.append((x, y))
```

The generation of your `gameArea` can be done in a single line of code:

```
let gameArea = (1...10).map{ x in (1...10).map{ y in (x: x, y: y) }}
```

The tuple members can be accessed by index `.0, .1, ...`, or by name (if they have names:

```
gameArea[0].x //equivalent to gameArea[0].0
```